# redirect /subdirectory to /symlink/subdirectory where /symlink points to /

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-7, symlink

i'm working on a drupal7 multisite setup based on subdirectories where example.com is used for the main website and example.com/subsite is another standalone drupal install. subsite is a symlink located in the root directory and also pointing to the root directory to give the subsite access to drupal core files.

now i have to make static content available via example.com/subsite/static, so i created a directory static in the root directory. that all works fine.

the problem is, that example.com/static is now also accessable and i want to prevent that.

i tried to redirect all requests to /static to /subsite/static resulting in inconsistent behaviour and redirect loops.

directory structure:

```
/
/{various drupal directories}
/subsite -> /
/static
```

rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/static/(.*)$ /subsite/static/$1 [R,L]
```

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed the redirect loops by using a rewrite condition, should have thought of that before.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subsite/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^static/(.*)$ /subsite/static/$1 [L,R=301]
```

thx anyway @florian-lemaitre for trying to help me

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
RewriteBase /    
RewriteRule ^static/(.*)$ /subsite/static/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^subsite/static/(.*)$ /static/$1 [L]
```

- In the first line we redirect all call to `/static/` to `/subsite/static/`.
- In the second line we rewrite all call to `/subsite/static/` to `/static`.

If it doesn't work please post your whole `.htaccess` file.

Comment: unfortunatelly your solution is causing redirect loops too, i was able to solve the problem by excluding the rewrite rule from requests that include the subsite